# Repeating a large form in a form wizard

Tags: django, django-forms, django-formwizard

I'm trying to create a form wizard which starts with a repeatable form for adding multiple trainees.

The user can add as many trainees as they like, with each of the "Add Trainee" forms being quite a long form asking for lots of details.

Once the user has added all of their trainees, there are 3 or 4 more forms before the wizard is complete.

What is the best way to do this?

I was wondering whether adding the trainees to the session would be the simplest idea but this might break some of the wizard functionality, like being able to go back etc.

And because the "Add Trainee" form is so long, it doesn't make sense to use a formset on the first form wizard page, I don't think.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to get away with modifying the `post` method with something like this.

```
if form.is_valid():
    # if the form is valid, store the cleaned data and files.
    self.storage.set_step_data(self.steps.current,
                               self.process_step(form))
    self.storage.set_step_files(self.steps.current,
                                self.process_step_files(form))

    # check if the current step is the last step
    if self.steps.current == self.steps.last:
        # no more steps, render done view
        return self.render_done(form, **kwargs)

    # check if trainee form is current form
    elif self.steps.current == "trainee_form":
        mentor = User.objects.get(id=self.request.user.id)
        Trainee.objects.create(
            mentor=mentor,
            data1=self.request.POST["trainee_form-data1"]
            data2=self.request.POST["trainee_form-data2"]
            data3=self.request.POST["trainee_form-data3"]
        )
        if self.request.POST["trainee_form-add_new"] == True:
            self.render.go_to_step["trainee_form"]
        else:
            return self.render_next_step(form)
    else:
        # proceed to the next step
        return self.render_next_step(form)
return self.render(form)
```

You'll have to fiddle with it, but hopefully it sparks an idea.